# div outside of another div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, overflow

I have a problem with my code. I want to put .calories, .proteins, .fats and .hydrates inside a .progress, but, they go out on the outside. I draw a border to see it better. Somebody could help me? :(

html:

```
<div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="progress hidden">
    <div class="calories"></div>
    <div class="proteins"></div>
    <div class="fats"></div>
    <div class="hydrates"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.calories, .proteins, .fats, .hydrates {
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
}

.col-xl-6 {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.progress {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

[As you see it on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65SUH.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/89hqr3uw/

Comment: `.progress` is a special class in bootstrap. Do you mean to use it that way? works if you don't use that class name http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/qmaKmG

Comment: @MichaelCoker you solved my error! I didn't know that .progress was a special class!! Thank you so so much!

Comment: @LuciaBRguez no problem.